# How to broadcast a message from a Phoenix Controller to a Channel?

Tags: elixir, channel, phoenix-framework

Is there a way to broadcast a message to a channel from outside that channel?

Maybe something like `Channel.broadcast topic, event, data`?

I saw something like this [here](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/70) but the final version of `Phoenix.Channel.broadcast/3` (as of today) takes a socket which implies the channel and topic.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use `MyApp.Endpoint.broadcast(topic, event, msg)` for that.

Check http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Endpoint.html

Comment: Note if you are running this from iex, you will need to start your application with `iex -S mix phoenix.server` for it to work.

Comment: That's something I should probably have found by myself :-) ... and I googled really hard but this thing didn't come up. Maybe it's for the best that it's here now.

Comment: Cloned this example https://github.com/chrismccord/phoenix_chat_example and works fine but if I enter to `iex -S mix` and then run Chat

`Chat.Endpoint.broadcast "rooms:lobby", "new:msg", %{"user" => "Boris", "body" => "Tes msg"}
` it doesn't appear the message in the browser

Comment: @BorisBarroso You need to do `iex -S mix phoenix.server` to make sure Pheonix also starts up. You can't broadcast if you only do `iex -S mix` because it doesn't start the server.

Comment: Thanks @Gazler!  I didn't know that and I was going crazy trying to send messages from iex!

Comment: In different examples it sometimes `room:lobby`, and sometimes `rooms:lobby`. It's hard to spot the difference, and with it broadcast just "doesn't work", there are no easy ways to debug.