# Broadcast a message to a phoenix channel from a mix task

Tags: redis, elixir, phoenix-framework

I found this answer to determine how to broadcast a message from a controller to a channel:

[How to broadcast a message from a Phoenix Controller to a Channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33960207/how-to-broadcast-a-message-from-a-phoenix-controller-to-a-channel)

What I need however is to publish a message to a channel from a mix task or potentially a Toniq worker. In this case the process may or may not be on the same machine.

Now if I understand correctly channels use either some in memory pub/sub or can be backed by other distributed queues.

If this is correct how could I have the channels backed by redis and have my worker/task publish to redis that would trigger a broadcast to the connected sockets?

Comment: You probably want to start here: http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/mix/

Comment: You can talk to other nodes, see http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/distributed-tasks-and-configuration.html - should work out-of-the-box from Mix as long as you set things up correctly (node names, cookies) and no intermediaries required as long as you stay inside the OTP ecosystem.