# How to broadcast a message from console or any module in Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, channel, phoenix-framework

I have tried this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33960207/how-to-broadcast-a-message-from-a-phoenix-controller-to-a-channel)
and also have tried this, maybe I might be doing something wrong with the answer and also tried this code [from youtube](https://youtu.be/RPs4SHpSThU?t=1951)

```
Phoenix.Channel.broadcast "rooms", "lobby", "new:msg", %{user: "User", body: "Hello from console"}
```

but none of them can add new messages to the [chat project example](https://github.com/chrismccord/phoenix_chat_example) any help would be great.

Comment: Are you trying to run from within Iex?

Comment: Yes `iex -S mix` and then run inside the console

Comment: See how details help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to run server in order for this to work.

```
iex -S mix phoenix.server
```

And then in IEX:

```
Phoenix.Channel.broadcast "rooms", "lobby", "new:msg", %{user: "User", body: "Hello from console"}
```

It is not enough to run just

```
Iex -S mix
```

as in that case there is nothing listening for events.

Comment: running `iex -S mix phoenix.server` has error
=INFO REPORT==== 9-Mar-2016::17:07:04 ===
    application: logger
    exited: stopped
    type: temporary
** (Mix) Could not start application chat: Chat.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: Chat.Endpoint
    ** (EXIT) shutdown: failed to start child: Phoenix.Endpoint.Server
        ** (EXIT) shutdown: failed to start child: {:ranch_listener_sup, Chat.Endpoint.HTTP}
            ** (EXIT) shutdown: failed to start child: :ranch_acceptors_sup
                ** (EXIT) {:listen_error, Chat.Endpoint.HTTP, :eaddrinuse}

Comment: :eaddrinuse means there is already something listening on port.